# Find the sum of digits and check the remainder when dividing by 8

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want a Python or a shell script to examine numbers in a particular range. For each number, find the sum of its digits, divide the sum by 8, and if the remainder is between 1 to 4 print that number.

Example.

> 5959
>
> 5+9+5+9 = 28

Remainder of 28 / 8 is 4.

4 comes in the range of 1 to 4, so print the number 5959 and go to next number. If the remainder is not in the range of 1 to 4 ignore it and go to next number.

So far I have tried this, but it doesn't do what I expect.

```
count = 0
lower = 5959
while (count<1000):
 sum_digit= lower%8

 count+=1
 lower+=1
 if 1<=sum_digit<=4:
  print lower
```

Comment: `sum_digit` is giving 5959 modulo 8 not the sum of the digits

Comment: i require the reminder of sum of digits..

Comment: Isn't the "remainder of 28 / 8" really "4 / 8", or "0.5"? And the modulus of `28 % 8` is 4. Currently, you have `sum_digit = 5959 % 8`, which is `7`

Comment: @cricket_007 the remainder of 28/8 is usually understood to be 4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to find the remainder mod 8 of the sum of digits of each number. Doing `lower%8` just finds the remainder mod 8 of the number itself.

The simplest way in Python to sum the digits of a number is to first convert it to a string so you can loop over the individual digits. Then convert each of those digits back to integers so you can do arithmetic with them.

To keep the output manageable, I'll use a smaller range:

```
for n in range(5959, 5980):
    if 0 < sum(map(int, str(n))) % 8 < 5:
        print(n)
```

**output**

```
5959
5960
5965
5966
5967
5968
5974
5975
5976
5977
```

If you don't want to use the `map` function you can use a generator expression:

```
for n in range(5959, 5980):
    if 0 < sum(int(d) for d in str(n)) % 8 < 5:
        print(n)
```

---

FWIW, this can be written on one line, but IMHO my earlier versions are far more readable:

```
print(*(u for u in range(5959,5980)if 0<sum(map(int,str(u)))%8<5),sep='\n')
```

Comment: Your script misses 5961 that satisfies the condition.

Comment: @Fomalhaut 5+9+6+1 = 21, and 21 = 2*8 + 5. The remainder of 5 is not in the requested range of 1 to 4.

Answer (score 2):

If I were you, for calculating the sum of numbers, I would have done like:

```
>>> my_num = 5959
>>> sum(int(i) for i in str(my_num))
28
```

In your current code, I do not see you calculating the `sum` of numbers.

Comment: Definately more pythonic than my solution with the `for` loop. Still i wonder if hiro protagonists solution isn't faster because there's no casting going on.

Answer (score 2):

or a version not using `str`:

```
count = 0
lower = 5959
while lower:
    count += lower % 10
    lower //= 10     # //= for python 3; /= for python 2
```

this just calculates the sum of the digits.

Comment: This just does the digit summing, it doesn't do the mod 8 stuff. And because of the way Python works, it's slower than my trick of `sum(map(int, str(n)))` because `str` does its arithmetic at C speed.

Comment: @PM2Ring: yes, that's just for the sum of the digits - as stated. about the speed: a quick benchmark with `timeit` says my version is a bit faster - yours scales better though... (for 100 digits mine is still slightly ahead).

Comment: Ah, ok. I didn't see your edit since I hadn't refreshed the page. I'm surprised that my version is a little slower in timeit tests. I haven't done a speed test of these algorithms today, but I'm pretty sure I've tested them in the past...

Comment: I've just written [my own timeit code](https://gist.github.com/PM2Ring/8f2cf8d5046d0873bb95ed71c1d05e45), along with a few more digit-summing functions. The timings depend on the Python version: on Python 3.6 my map-based version is faster than your algorithm when the number of digits is 20 or more, but in Python 2.6 the cross-over doesn't occur until the number of digits is 60. For large numbers of digits, the fastest way to convert a digit char to an integer is to do a lookup of a local dictionary; a default argument is an efficient way to supply that dict.

Comment: BTW, the `//` floor division operator should be used when appropriate in Python 2 code; the docs have been advising that since Python 2.3, IIRC.

Comment: @PM2Ring: wow, thanks! (my benchmark was on ubuntu 16.04; python 3.5.2).

Answer (score 0):

See if this works:

```
number = 5959
sum = 0
for digit in str(number):
    sum += int(digit)
mod = sum % 8
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def main():
    count = 0
    lower = 5959
    while (count<1000):
        lowersum = sum_digits(lower)
        sum_digit= lower%8
        count+=1
        lower+=1
        if 1<=sum_digit<=4:
            print (sum_digit,lowersum)

def sum_digits(n):
    sum = 0
    while n:
        sum += n % 10
        n //= 10
    return sum
main()
```

Hope this will work